# How to change this if statement into a Ternary operator?

Tags: javascript

I want to turn this if statement into a Ternary Operator.

```js
if (
  (Vi_TDO1 != "TD") && 
  (Vi_TDO2 != "TD") && 
  (Vi_TDO3 != "TD") && 
  (Vi_TDO4 != "TD") && 
  (Vi_TDO5 != "TD") && 
  (Vi_TDO6 != "TD") && 
  (Vi_TDO7 != "TD") && 
  (Vi_TDO8 != "TD") && 
  (Vi_TDO9 != "TD") && 
  (Vi_TD10 != "TD") && 
  (Vi_TD11 != "TD") && 
  (Vi_TD12 != "TD")) {
  Opt_TDTD = "NO";
} else {
  Opt_TDTD = "YES";
}
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: Ask positive

Comment: how do you populate this variables `Vi_TDO` + n?

Comment: @NinaScholz I was also thinking [...window.Vi_TD
.....]

Comment: Create an array and use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) on it: `Opt_TDTD  = [Vi_TDO1, Vi_TD02, ..., Vi_TD12].includes("TD") ? "YES" : "NO"`

Answer (score 0):

That would be

```js
Opt_TDTD = (Vi_TDO1 != "TD") && (Vi_TDO2 != "TD") && (Vi_TDO3 != "TD") && (Vi_TDO4 != "TD") && (Vi_TDO5 != "TD") && (Vi_TDO6 != "TD") && (Vi_TDO7 != "TD") && (Vi_TDO8 != "TD") && (Vi_TDO9 != "TD") && (Vi_TD10 != "TD") && (Vi_TD11 != "TD") && (Vi_TD12 != "TD")
    ? "NO" : "YES"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can think of a easier solution for your variable checking ^^

But here is the solution:

```js
const result = ((Vi_TDO1 != "TD") && (Vi_TDO2 != "TD") && (Vi_TDO3 != "TD") && (Vi_TDO4 != "TD") && (Vi_TDO5 != "TD") && (Vi_TDO6 != "TD") && (Vi_TDO7 != "TD") && (Vi_TDO8 != "TD") && (Vi_TDO9 != "TD") && (Vi_TD10 != "TD") && (Vi_TD11 != "TD") && (Vi_TD12 != "TD")) ? "NO" : "YES";
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use an array with every

```
Opt_TDTD = [Vi_TDO1, Vi_TDO2, Vi_TDO3, Vi_TDO4, Vi_TDO5, Vi_TDO6,
            Vi_TDO7, Vi_TDO8, Vi_TDO9, Vi_TD10, Vi_TD11, Vi_TD12]
              .every(x => x === 'TD') ? 'YES' : 'NO'
```

Comment: Test was None of them TD

Answer (score 0):

this Would work

```
const tdsArray = [Vi_TDO1, Vi_TD02,...,Vi_TD12] 
const Opt_TDTD = tdsArray.every(td => td !== 'TD') ? "NO" :  "YES";
console.log(Opt_TDTD);
```

Comment: [Already answered 10 minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62200768/295783)